# Arithmetic series question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hello can anyone help me with question.

In an arithmetic series the terms of the series are equally spread out. For example in $1+5+9+13+17$ consecutive terms are $4$ apart. If the first term in an arithmetic series is $3$ the last term is $136$ and the sums is $1390$ what are the first 3 terms?